# How to achieve following in JavaScript using Regex

Tags: regex

I want to match following pattern and split it, How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Expected output of Regex from string

```
["any number", "only single alphabet", "+ OR -", 
 "only single alphabet", "+ OR -", "any single alphabet"]
```

or

```
["any number", "only single alphabet"]
```

or

```
["any number", "only single alphabet", "+ OR -", 
 "only single alphabet"]
```

Comment: Show your efforts, and which problem you encountered.

Comment: Are those actual outputs, or some kind of description of the output?

Comment: This seems very basic, a regex tutorial should explain how to do it.

Comment: I tried to achieve it but failed. I was able to match only /[0-9]+ after that I couldn't find how to continue matching exactly from there.

Answer (score -1):

It was solved by using this Regex, I don't know it's perfect solution or not but it works however I want.

```
/(^[0-9]+)([a-z])([+-]?)([a-z]?)([+-]?)([a-z]?)/g
```